# Feature Selection Techniques

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I am completely new to statistical modelling.I wanted to know what are the feature selection techniques.

Say I have 10 variables but I need to what are actual important one's among them.

I have read about feature selection on internet and came to know few of the techniques:

1. Correlation
2. Forward Selection
3. Backward Elimination

But I am not getting how can I use them.
How can a correlation be used in feature selection.
How to perform a Forward Selection/Backward Elimination etc.

What models I can use for feature selection.
I just want a high level overview of it.
When to use what

Some one help me to get started

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful resource for learning more about feature selection: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf

Salient points from the resource:

> 1. **Do you have domain knowledge?** If yes, construct a better set of ad hoc features
> 2. **Are your features commensurate?** If no, consider normalizing them.
> 3. **Do you suspect interdependence of features?** If yes, expand your feature set by constructing conjunctive features or products of features, as much as your computer resources allow you.
> 4. **Do you need to prune the input variables (e.g. for cost, speed or data understanding reasons)?** If no, construct disjunctive features or weighted sums of feature
> 5. **Do you need to assess features individually (e.g. to understand their influence on the system or because their number is so large that you need to do a first filtering)?** If yes, use a variable ranking method; else, do it anyway to get baseline results.
> 6. **Do you need a predictor?** If no, stop
> 7. **Do you suspect your data is “dirty” (has a few meaningless input patterns and/or noisy outputs or wrong class labels)?** If yes, detect the outlier examples using the top ranking variables obtained in step 5 as representation; check and/or discard them.
> 8. **Do you know what to try first?** If no, use a linear predictor. Use a forward selection method with the “probe” method as a stopping criterion or use the 0-norm embedded method for comparison, following the ranking of step 5, construct a sequence of predictors of same nature using increasing subsets of features. Can you match or improve performance with a smaller subset? If yes, try a non-linear predictor with that subset.
> 9. **Do you have new ideas, time, computational resources, and enough examples?** If yes, compare several feature selection methods, including your new idea, correlation coefficients, backward selection and embedded methods. Use linear and non-linear predictors. Select the best approach with model selection
> 10. **Do you want a stable solution (to improve performance and/or understanding)?** If yes, subsample your data and redo your analysis for several “bootstrap”.

Here is another useful resource:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/

Salient points from the resource:

> **Univariate Selection**
>   Statistical tests can be used to select those features that have the strongest relationship with the output variable.
>   **Recursive Feature Elimination**
>   The Recursive Feature Elimination (or RFE) works by recursively removing attributes and building a model on those attributes that remain.
>   **Feature Importance**
>   Bagged decision trees like Random Forest and Extra Trees can be used to estimate the importance of features.